# Spring MVC — Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working on a Spring 4.0 MVC application, and my JSP won't come up when i want to update a row from table but works for adding a new row. I am getting the following in my browser screen.

```
août 03, 2016 11:43:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/webapp] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute] with root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.formulaire_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005finput_005f0(formulaire_jsp.java:370)
    at    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.formulaire_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fform_005f0(formulaire_jsp.java:317)
    at    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.formulaire_jsp._jspService(formulaire_jsp.java:231)
    at    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) 
    at    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:715)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:460)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) 
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1419)
    at    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:44)
    at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

here is the controller i used

```
@Controller
public class BateauController {

@Autowired
private BateauInterMetier metierBat;


@RequestMapping(value="/bateau",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView bateaux()
{   ModelAndView modelview=new ModelAndView();
    modelview.addObject("listeBateau", metierBat.getAll());
    modelview.setViewName("bateau");
    return modelview;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/ajouterBateau")
public ModelAndView ajouter()
{   System.out.println("ajouterBateau");
    ModelAndView modelview=new ModelAndView();
    modelview.addObject("command", new Bateau());
    System.out.println("ajouterBateau-command");
    modelview.setViewName("formulaire");
    System.out.println("ajouterBateau-formulaire");
    return modelview;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/modifier/{matricule}")
public ModelAndView modifier(@PathVariable("matricule") String matricule)
{   System.out.println("modifierBateau");
    ModelAndView modelview=new ModelAndView();
    modelview.addObject("command", metierBat.getById(matricule));
    System.out.println("modifierBateau-command");
    modelview.setViewName("formulaire");
    System.out.println("modifierBateau-formulaire");
    return modelview;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/ValiderAjoutBateau")
public ModelAndView validerAjout(@ModelAttribute("command") Bateau bateau)
{   System.out.println("avant modifier");
    metierBat.modifier(bateau);
    System.out.println("modifier");
    ModelAndView modelview=new ModelAndView();
    modelview.setViewName("redirect:/bateau");
    return modelview;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/supprimer/{id}")
public String suprimmer(@PathVariable("id") String id)

{   Bateau bateau=new Bateau(id);
    metierBat.supprimer(bateau);
    return "redirect:/bateau";
}
}
```

and the two jsp files :

`bateau.jsp`

```
<f:form>
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <a href="<c:url value='/ajouterBateau' />">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                                        Ajouter Bateau
                                    </button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Matricule</th>
                                            <th>Nom Bateau</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <c:forEach items="${listeBateau}" var="bateau">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>${bateau.matBateau}</td>
                                                <td>${bateau.nomBateau}</td>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="<c:url value='/modifier/${bateau.matBateau}' />">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                            aria-label="Left Align">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                </a></td>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="<c:url value='/supprimer/${bateau.matBateau}' />">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                                                            aria-label="Left Align">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                </a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </f:form>
```

and `formulaire.jsp`

```
<form role="form" action="ValiderAjoutBateau">
                            <f:form method="POST" commandName="command">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="matricule">Matricule Bateau:</label>
                                    <f:input type="text" class="form-control" id="matricule"
                                        placeholder="Matricule Bateau" path="matBateau"></f:input>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nom">Nom Bateau:</label>
                                    <f:input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom"
                                        placeholder="Nom Bateau" path="nomBateau"></f:input>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
                            </f:form>
```

Comment: Please format the log fragment you included at the top. Also, it is unclear what exactly you want to achieve. If you need help with debugging, StackOverflow is probably not the best choice.

Comment: Try changing commandName="command" to modelAttribute="command"      Using commandName was old way of doing it. Also I see two form tag in  formulaire.jsp, one for action and one for method and command name. Any particular requirement for doing this? Shouldn't you be using one form tag for defining action and attribute?

Comment: The error says that Spring did not find a valid `Bateau` object in model under the name `"command"`. Could the result of `metierBat.getById(matricule)` be null?